# Is there an international competition that yearly chooses the best drones in the world?

Tags: competitions

**Is there an international competition that chooses the best drones in the world?**

Is there a yearly “Oscar” for drones, somewhere?

If so what are various categories that are listed?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=annual+drones+award

There are a few like UAE Drones for good award, and drone photography awards, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any *international* competition for "Best Drone". The closest thing to that would be recommendations that experienced pilots make and it would depend on what that person liked.

I imagine that if there was an international "Best drone" competition it would have categories such as fastest racing drone, best freestyle drone, best photography drone, most popular drone, etc.